# Problem deploying package using Ant migration to a new org

Tags: deployment

I am trying to deploy a new package from my test org to new org. But I am running into some issues due to one standard field in Account object. Field is IsCustomerPortal this field is created when community is enabled in salesforce org. My Source org has community enabled but in my target org they are not. As a result this field is failing the deployment to target. Any help would be appricated.

Comment: just make that field has disable and push to your target org.seems like you havent done any community setting in target org

Comment: Yes InMy Target org community is not enabled and i cannot enable them in target org

Comment: just make this field disable and push it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually tweak the metadata-xml file for the object and make sure you remove the community related metadata from the xml and try deploying .